# Swift generic codable struct is hard to work with

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I have this simple codable struct that represents a JSON response for many different API index endpoints:

```
struct JsonDocument<Resource: Mappable> : Codable {
  var data: [Resource]
  var cursor: String? // pagination cursor
}
```

`Mappable` looks something like this:

```
protocol Mappable : Codable {
  static var dependencies: [MappableType] { get }
  var id: Int64 { get set }
  var deleted: Bool? { get }
  var created_at: Date { get set }
  var updated_at: Date { get set }
}

// this enum lets me associate core data entities to mappable structs (more info in comments)
@objc enum MappableType : Int16, CaseIterable {
  case event = 1
  case venue = 2
  ....

  func getType() -> Mappable.Type {
    switch self
      ... return EventResource.self
  }
}
```

And a concrete type might look something like this:

```
struct EventResource : Mappable {
  ... id, deleted, etc
  var name: String
  static var dependencies: [SyncableType] { return [.venue] }
}
```

The problem is I'm now finding this JsonDocument structure hard to work with. For example, I need to create `DownloadOperation`'s (subclass of `Operation`) for each entity type (`EventResource`, etc) and configure dependencies. I found I had to declare the `DownloadOperation` with a generic parameter like so `DownloadOperation<Resource: Mappable> : Operation` in order to pass the `Mappable type` to the `JsonDocument`. I.e., the `mappable type` can't be an `init()` argument because you can't do `var type: Mappable.Type ...and then: JsonDocument<type>`.

With `DownloadOperation` now taking a generic parameter, I can't for example loop over all my `MappableType` (that I define in an `enum`), create operations, and configure dependencies:

`let operations = [DownloadOperation<???>]`

I want to be able to do something like:

```
// pseudo-code
var operations = [DownloadOperation<???>]()

for mappable in MappableType.allCases {
  operations.append(mappable.downloadOperation)
}

for operation in operations {
  operation.Resource.configureDependencies(operations)
}

// add operations to queue
```

Eventually these structs get mapped to Core data objects in a separate `MappingOperation` subclass. The reason for dependencies is that the JSON responses are flat objects and only return foreign keys for relationships. For example, the `/events` endpoint would return `venue_id`'s. Therefore, I need to run the `DownloadOperation<VenueResource>` operation before the `DownloadOperation<EventResource>` operation.

Any tips? I'm new to Swift. Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of the `MappableType` enum?

Comment: @Alexander I have a core data entity called `SyncResource`. I create exactly one of these for each core data entity (e.g. Event, Ticket). Properties on `SyncResource` include: clientCount, serverCount, etc and this MappableType enum which enables me to associate it back to the right core data Entity and Mappable struct. MappableType is CaseIterable so that I can create each `SyncResource` on app boot by looping over the enum. Another function not shown here on the enum lets me get the right `Mappable.Type` class

Comment: Declaring `var operations = [Operation]()` doesn't work?

Comment: @Cristik That loses my type information. I need to loop back over the operations, grab the generic Resource type class, and build dependencies between the operations.

Comment: Well... in that case... you might need a type eraser.